# php Duplicate content

Tags: php, duplicates

I have file txt and in the file I have phone numbers.

I want to filter out that the duplicate numbers. How I could do it using PHP?

Each number is a new line `/r/n`

Comment: save your self a world of pain, and start using a data base.

Comment: Sounds like an class assignment to me..

Comment: depends how big the text file is. if this is a one time thing, just use Excel. if this is something created/used by your code, use a real database instead of flat files as Dagon has mentioned.

Comment: no internet when I did homework, I'm jealous

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- Parse the string into an array, via [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- Filter out the dups, via [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = Array();
$numbers = file('mydata.txt');
$numbers = array_unique($numbers);
```

Comment: Great, although `file` just returns an array. You don't need the first line.

Comment: True, yet for readability, it doesn't hurt to initialize it there.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
$numbers = array_unique(file('phones.txt'));

print_r($numbers);
```

Used functions [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Good luck!

---

Further explanation.

The `file()` will:

> Returns the file in an array. Each
>   element of the array corresponds to a
>   line in the file...

So you can use to your advantage that the phones are one on each line.

---

Note:

Just in case I may clarify that this won't work if the .txt file actually has `/r/n`

```
123/r/n
456/r/n
123/r/n
789/r/n
```

---

More:

You can find [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) `file_get_contents()` useful but it turns everything into a string NOT an array.

Answer (score 0):

file(), reads in to array
array_unique() remove the duplicates
implode() recreate the per line format
file_put_contents() write the file back